# Ajax, jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery form which I created as follows

```
<div data-role="page" id="page3" data-theme="d" >

<div data-role="header">
 <h1 style="font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;font-  size:23px">LetsAllSave</h1>
```

```
<div data-role="content">

<form action="passenger.php" data class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" method="post" id="passengerfrmsignup" >

<fieldset>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="name">
      <em>* </em> Name: </label>
      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name, at least 5 characters"
        name="name" class="required" minlength=5 data-mini="true" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g,'');"/>
  </div>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="surname">
      <em>* </em> Surname: </label>
      <input type="text" id="surname" placeholder="Surname, at least 5 characters"
        name="surname" class="required" minlength=5 data-mini="true" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g,'');"/>
  </div>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="phone">
      <em>* </em> Phone: </label>
      <input type="tel" id="phone" placeholder="phone format: 05xxxxxxxxx"
        name="phone" class="required" number=true   minlength="11" maxlength="11" data-mini="true"/>
  </div>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="email">
      <em>* </em> Email: </label>
      <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="eg. someone@gmail.com"
        name="email" class="required email" data-mini="true"/>
  </div>

  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="password"> 
      <em>* </em>Password: </label>
      <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="At least 5 character password"
        name="password" class="required" minlength=5 data-mini="true"/>
  </div>
   <div id="container">  </div> 
  <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
    <input  type="submit" value="Register"
      id="pass-signup" data-theme="d"/>
  </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I also have the passenger.php file as follows just to keep it simple:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['surname'],$_POST['phone'],
$_POST['email'],$_POST['password'])) {
print_r($_POST);
}
else echo "data not set"; 

?>
```

**NOTE**: I validated my form inputs as follows:

```
$( "#passengerfrmsignup" ).validate({
submitHandler: function( form ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        dataType : 'json'
    success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
           alert("successful");
        }
    });
return false; // required to block normal submit since you used ajax



 }
 });
```

Using jquery.form-validator.min.js and it's working fine. However, after all the fields are correctly filled and the form submitted the passenger.php file returns "data not set".

What might be the problem? I have done a lot of research in vain.

Comment: Have you tried doing a var_dump($_POST) to see what values are being sent?  Also may be a good idea using chrome browser developer tool (pressing F12), in the "network" tab, you may see what data the browser is sending to the server.

Comment: get rid of the if-statement and just output `$_POST` no matter what was actually sent, that way you can see what's missing. If you still can't figure out what's wrong, reinstate your ìf(isset(...))` but just one key at a time, so you can see which one fails.

Comment: @mmgross Array ( ) is printed after removing the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [JQuery .serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) return URL params (`name=test&surname=cool`), you need to specify `type: "POST"` in your AJAX request.

You can also check your param with `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET` to check that you are able to see your variables server side.

Comment: I set type:"POST" but the output is same.

Comment: @lil and about $_REQUEST? Can you see the request in the browser debug tools (F12, tab network in Chrome for example)

Comment: how to I close the topic?

Answer (score 0):

change your passenger.php page to:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['surname']) && isset($_POST['phone']) &&
isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['surname']) && !empty($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
print_r($_POST);
}
else echo "data not set"; 

?>
```

and your javascript/jQuery

```
$( "#passengerfrmsignup" ).validate({
submitHandler: function( form ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: $form.serialize()
    success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
           alert("successful");
        }
    });
return false; // required to block normal submit since you used ajax



 }
 });
```

Comment: try with the above ajax

Answer (score -2):

Try with this code snippet:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){

   if(isset($value)){
      return true; // variable is set
   }else{
      return false; //varible is not set
   }

}
```

Comment: should I include this on the php or js file